# How to solve cwd error in VScode, using SSH connection to WSL with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: c, ubuntu, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote-ssh

I've made some decent progress in configuring WSL for vscode, fixing random error after random error, but I've ran into one with the following output when attempting to launch the debugger:

> launch: workingDirectory '${fileDirName}' does not exist.

This happens with any path I try, and I've searched everywhere for fixes, nothing seems to work. I tried setting the default terminal path to bash in terminal settings, and tried using different names for the directory in `launch.json`, but I'm honestly defeated at this point.